# Saving a paypal account for a user to my web application

Tags: paypal

I have a web application that allows users to purchase products online. I would like a user to add a paypal account to his or her account such that the next time, he or she needs to checkout, the paypal on file shall be used.

I do not want to store the payal details on my server instead i am looking for a service like paypal credit card vault.

An advantage for saving the paypal on vault is a user shall not be needed to enter email and password all over again.

Does paypal have a service like the one i describe?.

Comment: I seriously doubt it since that would open up a huge security hole for PayPal. Even EBay doesn't do that and they own PayPal.

Comment: Yeah i though that as well so i thought one touch uses some kind of a paypal account vault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  It's done by creating a Billing Agreement and then processing future Reference Transactions based on that billing agreement.

This gives you a lot of power to process any amount at any time without further approval from the buyer.  As such, this requires heavy vetting from PayPal.

They will only approve you for it if you're doing very high volume (millions of dollars per year) in most cases.  But yes, it can be done.

Keep in mind that PayPal itself provides a "[One Touch](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/one-touch-checkout)" feature so people can quickly checkout without entering credentials in the future.  So they've basically built what you're wanting to do directly into the Express Checkout experience.